# How to convert local kendoUI scatter chart example to remote data source?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-dataviz

I am attempting to convert the local data source example found at [KendoUI scatter chart example](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/dataviz/scatter-charts/index.html) to a remote data source.

If I take the data into a JSON file and then configure the data source using the transport option pointing to this JSON file, I can see it being retrieved over the network. But nothing displays on the chart.

What am I missing? Is it a parameterMap issue? A schema issue? Something with series config?

I'm in the dark, so any help is greatly appreciated. :)

EDIT:
I'm not sure how to post JSON resource to jsfiddle, so I'll just show the code bits here.

```
    <div kendo-chart k-options="scatter"  k-theme="'silver'" k-data-source="fakeData">
    </div>
```

Above shows the HTML portion.

```
 $scope.scatter ={
        title: {
            position: "top",
            text: "Rainfall - Wind Speed"
        },
        legend: {
            position: "bottom"
        },
        seriesDefaults: {
        type: "scatter"
        },
        xAxis: {
            max: 35,
            title: {
                text: "Wind Speed [km/h]"
            },
            crosshair: {
                visible: true,
                tooltip: {
                    visible: true,
                    format: "n1"
                }
            }
        },


        yAxis: {
            min: -5,
            max: 25,
            title: {
                text: "Rainfall [mm]"
            },
            axisCrossingValue: -5,
            crosshair: {
                visible: true,
                tooltip: {
                    visible: true,
                    format: "n1"
                }
            }
        }
    };

    $scope.fakeData = new kendo.data.DataSource({

        transport: {
            read:  "data/scatter-chart.json",
            type: "json"
        }
    });
```

Above is the controller code.

> [{
>       "name": "January 2008",
>       "data": [
>           [16.4, 5.4], [21.7, 2], [25.4, 3], [19, 2], [10.9, 1], [13.6, 3.2], [10.9, 7.4], [10.9, 0], [10.9, 8.2], [16.4, 0], [16.4, 1.8], [13.6, 0.3], [13.6, 0], [29.9, 0], [27.1, 2.3], [16.4, 0], [13.6, 3.7], [10.9, 5.2], [16.4, 6.5], [10.9, 0], [24.5, 7.1], [10.9, 0], [8.1, 4.7], [19, 0], [21.7, 1.8], [27.1, 0], [24.5, 0], [27.1, 0], [29.9, 1.5], [27.1, 0.8], [22.1, 2]]
>   },{
>       "name": "January 2009",
>       "data": [
>           [6.4, 13.4], [1.7, 11], [5.4, 8], [9, 17], [1.9, 4], [3.6, 12.2], [1.9, 14.4], [1.9, 9], [1.9, 13.2], [1.4, 7], [6.4, 8.8], [3.6, 4.3], [1.6, 10], [9.9, 2], [7.1, 15], [1.4, 0], [3.6, 13.7], [1.9, 15.2], [6.4, 16.5], [0.9, 10], [4.5, 17.1], [10.9, 10], [0.1, 14.7], [9, 10], [2.7, 11.8], [2.1, 10], [2.5, 10], [27.1, 10], [2.9, 11.5], [7.1, 10.8], [2.1, 12]]
>   },{
>       "name": "January 2010",
>       "data": [
>           [21.7, 3], [13.6, 3.5], [13.6, 3], [29.9, 3], [21.7, 20], [19, 2], [10.9, 3], [28, 4], [27.1, 0.3], [16.4, 4], [13.6, 0], [19, 5], [16.4, 3], [24.5, 3], [32.6, 3], [27.1, 4], [13.6, 6], [13.6, 8], [13.6, 5], [10.9, 4], [16.4, 0], [32.6, 10.3], [21.7, 20.8], [24.5, 0.8], [16.4, 0], [21.7, 6.9], [13.6, 7.7], [16.4, 0], [8.1, 0], [16.4, 0], [16.4, 0]]
>   }]

Above is the JSON referred to in scatter-chart.json

NOTE: I have successfully done other, simpler Kendo chart implementations. So presume all Javascript and other requirements are correct. I receive no error on the console and can inspect the data object retrieved. It simply doesn't render. I am fairly certain there is some special handling of the nested "data" array that I am not correctly initializing.

Comment: Could you show your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the Chart widget reads data for a single series when used with a dataSource. So the JSON file should read:

```
[ [16.4, 5.4], [21.7, 2], [25.4, 3], [19, 2] ... ]
```

In order to have multiple series taken from the remote service, you would have to read them first, and then create the widget with the "series" config option set to the returned data. It can also be done after the widget was created by using `setOptions({series: data})`.

Comment: I suppose a "work around" is OK. But I'm still unclear why setting the series directly works, but via a data source something "extra" is needed.

Comment: I think it's just a limitation of the widget. It looks at the provided data source and expects to only have a list of data items there.